# Schedule task on specific time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timer, task, timing

which is the best way to start method on specific time (hour and min and sec ) on .net core worker

example  : start competition on 19/05/2020 6.00 AM for one time  i use below approach this approach delay two seconds:

```
 protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await CheckCompetitionStarted();
                await Task.Delay(5, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

 private async Task CheckCompetitionStarted()
        {
            try
            {
                var CurrentComp = _game.GetCurrentCompetition();

                if (CurrentComp != null)
                {
                    if (CurrentComp.PlandStartingTime.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date
                        && CurrentComp.PlandStartingTime.Hour == DateTime.UtcNow.Hour
                        && CurrentComp.PlandStartingTime.Minute == DateTime.UtcNow.Minute)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"Start Competition :{DateTime.Now} ");

                      await  CurrentComp.Start();

                        CurrentComp.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex,"");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
    public async Task RunAtTime(DateTime targetTime, Action action)
    {
        var remaining = targetTime - DateTime.Now ;
        if (remaining < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        await Task.Delay(remaining);
        action();
    }
```

Replace the `Task` and `Action` with `Task<T>` and `Func<T>` if you want a return value.

Replace `Action` with `Func<Task>` (or `Func<Task<T>>`) if you want to call an async method.

Comment: Any reasoning you decided to do `Action` instead of `Func<Task>` and await the `func`?

Comment: @Rand Random. I used the simplest abstraction for the example, added some alternatives in the answer.